# tableau count non zero values in a row

Tags: row, tableau-api

I have data in tableau like below

```
day       employee    expense_reason        expense
2/24/2018   abc   car mileage               $5 
2/24/2018   xyz   car mileage               $5 
2/24/2018   xyz   car rent                  $8 
2/24/2018   xyz   car rent                  $9
```

I want to find occasions when on a same day, single employee claims both expenses. I am producing below view in Tableau using 
day and employee as rows
expense reason as column
and sum(number of rows) as Text

i am getting grand total using analysis>>totals>>show row totals
instead of getting row totals, how could i get count of non zero values in a row

```
                  expense_reason        
day        employee   car mileage   car rent    grand total
2/24/2018   abc         1                         1
2/24/2018   xyz         1           2             3
```

## update 1

i tried below as per one of the answers but it is not giving output that i want[image]

Comment: did you try ZN function?

Comment: could you show an example of ZN function - how could i use it in the context of this example? i will research more too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should solve the No-Data part since there's no data for the combo abc-rent.

You can achieve this using the lookup function, forcing a fake lookup using 0 as parameter.
Something like this:

```
LOOKUP(SUM([Something]),0)
```

Then you can use ZN function to force a zero for a null value, which is different from No Data.

That being said, you should be able to get something like this:

[image]

Here's the Calculated field:

```
zn(LOOKUP(max({ FIXED [day],[employee],[reason] : COUNT([reason])}),0))
```

**EDIT**

If you want to have grand totals, i think this should be the better solution:

[image]

And the Calculated Field is a pure Count nested in a lookup function as said before:

```
zn(LOOKUP(COUNT([expense]),0))
```

Comment: in my measures field, i have created a column `xxx` as you have shown. But i am having hard time displaying that column at the end (in place of row totals). How could i do that? please explain steps

Comment: did the updated versione of the answer solved your problem?
if so, please accept the answer in order to close the thread